# Date::today not defined?

Tags: ruby, class, date

Why are only some methods of the Date class loaded without an explicit:

```
require 'date'
```

line?

For example:

```
irb(main):002:0> Date.today
NoMethodError: undefined method `today' for Date:Class
from (irb):2
from /Users/mwlang/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0/bin/irb:16:in `<main>'
```

And then...

```
irb(main):003:0> require 'date'
=> true
```

leads to...

```
irb(main):004:0> Date.today
=> #<Date: 2013-04-12 ((2456395j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>
```

The documentation at http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html seems to offer no explicit explanation for this behavior.  Comments on #irc say its a stdlib rather than core library, but core doesn't even have Date class defined and launching irc with -f (suppress reading .irbrc) to get a minimal load still appears to load some sort of base/core Date class.

Would like a technical explanation of what's going on and references to the Ruby docs that explain this so I understand for other such encounters as I switch from Ruby 1.8.7 to Ruby 2.0.0.

Comment: `Date` is an `stdlib` of Ruby. So we need to `include` that,if we want to use any of the methods under it. Probably your question is not clear.

Comment: So which `date`command seems to work without an explicit `require`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `Date` class you are seeing is defined in [lib/rubygems/specification.rb](https://github.com/rubygems/rubygems/blob/v2.3.0/lib/rubygems/specification.rb#L20) for compatibility reasons:

```
# date.rb can't be loaded for `make install` due to miniruby
# Date is needed for old gems that stored #date as Date instead of Time.
class Date; end
```

It's an empty class definition and it doesn't provide any methods or functionality.

If starting IRB without RubyGems, that Date class is gone:

```
$ ruby --disable-gems -S irb
irb(main):001:0> Date
NameError: uninitialized constant Date
```

#### Update

The empty `Date` class was removed in [RubyGems 2.4.0](https://github.com/rubygems/rubygems/blob/v2.4.0/History.txt#L45):

> - RubyGems no longer defines an empty Date class.  Pull Request [#948](https://github.com/rubygems/rubygems/pull/948) by Benoit
>     Daloze.

Comment: Thanks for the source reference and explanation!  Mystery solved.

Comment: Thats thats a great explanation!

Answer (score 1):

Complementing @Stefan answer:

Please note that This has been removed, in later version of rubygems.

- Changelog [here](https://github.com/rubygems/rubygems/blob/be819945ba1c788a5b589a9d5daa86e9dcaaba3f/History.txt#L148-L149)
- Merge Request [here](https://github.com/rubygems/rubygems/pull/948)