# Is there a default Ruby Date object?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, date

I happened to stumble on this while trying some code in `pry`:

```
>> Date.new(2015, 1, 8)                                                                           
ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (3 for 0)
from (pry):6:in `initialize'
>> require 'date'                                                                                 
=> true
>> Date.new(2015, 1, 8)
=> #<Date: 2015-01-08 ((2457031j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>
```

Note: This is a clean start of Pry, there are no custom constants with the name `Date`.

Questions:

1. Is there a default `Date` object already defined in `Ruby`?
2. What exactly is then being *required* by `require 'date'`?
3. Why such a variation in behavior?

Comment: You have answers for all your question in my link.

Comment: Thanks! Wasn't able to find it while searching!

Comment: I've just updated [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15974654/477037): the empty `Date` class was removed in RubyGems 2.4.0. Seems like you're running an outdated version ;)

Comment: Yup! Just checked to see I was on 2.0.0 :)